# How to make jQuery UI buttonset work with knockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I´m using the jQuery UI buttonset with knockout.
Somehow it works nice with a single "layer" (or scope) but when I apply the selection for an array the UI formatting disappears.

I guess it has something to do with ID, but cannot quite manage to figured it out.

My view model consists of two items:

```
self.items = ko.observableArray([
    new Title( {ID: 1, name: 'The first one', isBold: true, isItalic: false }),
    new Title( {ID: 2, name: 'The second one', isBold: false, isItalic: true, isUnderlined: true })
]); 
self.selected = ko.observable();
```

HTML:

```
<select data-bind="options:items, optionsCaption: 'Choose item...', optionsText: 'name', value: selected"></select>

<div id="format" data-bind="with: selected(), jqButtonset: {}">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myBold"   data-bind="checked: isBold" ><label for="myBold">B</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="myItalic"  data-bind="checked: isItalic"><label for="myItalic">I</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="myUnderlined" data-bind="checked: isUnderlined"><label for="myUnderlined">U</label>                                   
</div>
```

The binding goes like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqButtonset = {
    init: function (element) {
        $(element).buttonset(); // Turns the element into a jQuery UI button
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var currentValue = valueAccessor();
        $(element).buttonset("option", "disabled", currentValue.enable === false);
    }
};
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/cq0fvpe2/

All hints and suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: just to be clear, do you want it to be that when the top-level isBold is selected, it overrides the isBold for all Title items?

Comment: What about using the [Knockout-jqueryUI library](http://gvas.github.io/knockout-jqueryui/buttonset.html) instead of trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @dperry, I want to set the "isBold" etc for each item independently with a dynamical variable for each item; hence the "checked: selected.isBold". The Buttonset should update according to the isBold()-value of the selected item.

Comment: @Tyblitz Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried with the  Knockout-jqueryUI library but it still makes a mock of it. It seems the observables (selected.isBold() ) works great, but the way I am using the jQuery Bottonset will not cause it to update properly.

Comment: @Tyblitz Here´s an updated fiddle with the knockout-jqueryUi: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/cq0fvpe2/6/ The problem remain unsolved.

Comment: Of course it could be handled with css: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/pahmftm6/3/